# Все ошибки во время выполнения скрипта писать в лог

Tags: php

Как записывать любые возникающие во время выполнения скриптов ошибки и предупреждения в лог-файл? Таким образом, чтобы при их возникновении лог заполнятся автоматически, без лишних вставок и проверок в самом коде скриптов.
например:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: newVar in /home/admin/web/site.ru/public_html/page.php on line 137
```

Желательно в лог-файл в директорию сайта. .htaccess-ом можно настроить?

Comment: указанная вами строка и так в лог файл пишется.

Comment: обернуть все в `try catch`... консолидировать ошибки, потом если в catch вывалиться, обработать и записать в лог. Для лучшего понимания ошибки генерить свои `throw`

Comment: Вы не сможете просто взять и записать все ошибки, которые будут происходить с коде, потому что исполнение будет остановлено при первой же, и не пойдёт дальше. Поэтому это должно стать стандартом проверять что ошибок нет, или же правильно обрабатывать их.

Comment: Указанную ошибку я обнаружил совершенно случайно спустя 6 месяцев работы сайта. Причина возникновения в том, что при определенной ситуации (очень редкой) переменная не инициализировалась. Но хотелось бы такие ошибки и предупреждения времени выполнения  писать в лог в директорию соответствующего сайта на сервере. Если есть способ настроить .htaccess или сам php.ini, без изменения кода скриптов сайта - то подскажите.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov, это же php...

Answer (score 1):

Всем спасибо. Решение оказалось очевидным - раскомментировать строку в php.ini:

```
error_log = php_errors.log
```

Теперь логи пишутся в корневых директориях сайтов. И как верно заметил Александр Быченко, не забываем закрывать эти логи от просмотра.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, если требуется разбивка по каталогам доменов настроить парсер логов на том же php.
Читать последний лог, запоминая прочтенную строку, в строке ошибки пишется каталог возникновения, парсить путь и в этот каталог эту строку добавлять к логу домена. Так можно дублировать ошибки касаемые только этого домена. Правда решение далеко не самое изящное))

Попробуйте через .htaccess:

```
# Включаем логирование ошибок
php_flag  log_errors on
# Относительный путь к файлу лога. Файл error.log будет создаваться в одном каталоге с .htaccess
php_value error_log  ./error.log

# Закрываем файл лога ошибок от доступа
<Files error.log>
 Order allow,deny
 Deny from all
 Satisfy All
</Files>
```

Comment: Благодарю. Сейчас ковырялся в php.ini, раскомментировал error_log = php_errors.log и логи начали создаваться в корневых директориях сайтов

Comment: Как вам вот такой вариант сокрытия логов? интересно ваше мнение (там три строки):RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*.log$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule .* - [L,R=404]